# Applying python script to file

Tags: python, pipe

This is a simple ask but I can't find any information on how to do it: I have a python script that is designed to take in a text file of a specific format and perform functions on it--how do I pipe a test file into the python script such that it is recognized as `input()`? More specifically, the Python is derived from skeleton code I was given that looks like this:

```
def main():
    N = int(input())
    lst = [[int(i) for i in input().split()] for _ in range(N)]
    intervals = solve(N, lst)
    print_solution(intervals)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I just need to understand how to, from the terminal, input one of my test files to this script (and see the `print_solution` output)

Comment: please check out this link: https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-read-text-file/#:~:text=To%20read%20a%20text%20file%20in%20Python%2C%20you,the%20file%20using%20the%20file%20close%20%28%29%20method.

Comment: Edited to include skeleton code

Comment: You can redirect `stdin` to a script on the command line via something like : `python myscript.py <file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Use the fileinput module

input.txt

```
...input.txt contents
```

script.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import fileinput


def main():
    for line in fileinput.input():
        print(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

pipe / input examples:

```sh
$ cat input.txt | ./script.py
...input.txt contents

$ ./script.py < input.txt 
...input.txt contents
```

Comment: How do I avoid `The '<' operator is reserved for future use` error I keep getting? I've tried this in both the VSCode terminal and a Windows Powershell instance and both give me this error

Comment: I'm not sure if you are using windows. I only know that this works in bash / sh / zsh. Maybe you can use cygwin?

Answer (score 0):

You can take absolute or relative path in your `input()` function and then open this path via `open()`

```
filename = input('Please input absolute filename: ')

with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    # Do your stuff
```

Please let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for--I've updated the question to hopefully be a bit more specific, but all I need is a terminal command that can input a text file to a python script

Comment: How do you expect to enter the file in a terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

A) Use sys.stdin (import sys at the top of course)

or

B) Use the ArgumentParser (from argparse import ArgumentParser) and pass the file as an argument.

Assuming A it would look something like this:

```
python script.py < file.extension
```

Then in the script it would look like:

```
fData = []
for line in sys.stdin.readLines():
  fData.append(line)

# manipulate fData
```

There are a number of ways to achieve what you want. This is what I came up with off the top of my head. It may not be the best / efficient way, but it should work. I do a lot of file I/O with python at work and this is one of the ways I've achieved it in the past.

Note: If you want to write the manipulated lines back to the file use the argparse library.

Edit:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

def parseInput():
  parser = ArgumentParser(description = "Takes input file to read")
  parser.add_argument('-f', type = str,  default = None,  required = 
  True,  help  = "File to perform I/O on")
  args = parser.parse_args()
  return args

def main():
  args = parseInput()
  fData = []
  # perform rb
  with open(args.f, 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
      fData.append(line)

  # Perform data manipulations

  # perform wb
  with open(args.f, 'w') as f:
    for line in fData:
      f.write(line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Then on command line it would look like:

```
python yourScript.py -f fileToInput.extension
```

Comment: Okay I tried doing this but the terminal is throwing an error, specifically `The '<' operator is reserved for future use.` I imported `sys` and altered the skeleton code as specified, then ran `& [Python path] "[script path]" < [testcase path]` in my terminal

Comment: Sorry, I was mistakenly assuming you were using Linux. Are you using windows? 10 I presume? If so your best bet may be to use the built in argparse library.

EDIT: Have you tried using a Git bash shell?